# Best choice in this nginx configuration

Tags: wordpress, nginx, virtualhost, vhosts

Being building a virtualhost for wordpress, I would like to know if this set seems correct or not at all.

```
location / {

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

The second line comes from Nginx's website, in an example concerning Wordpress so not knowing if I should keep the first one or not; as much as I ask before doing stupid things. Can it be possible to directly merge the two parts into one ?

Answer (score 0):

You defenetly need only one rule to match "/" because the second rule will never be matched, so your rule should look like this:
 
`location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}`
 You can find more about nginx locations here: [Understanding Nginx Server and Location Block Selection Algorithms](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms#matching-location-blocks)

Comment: For the rules I suspected a little but at least you confirmed me that but what I wanted to know is what was the best to use for Wordpress.